# How to create a combobox with items displayed horizontally?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to create a combobox (drop down list) with items displayed horizontally like grid. I searched through the net, but could find the template or any third party component that allow me to create. I am looking for any suggestion of component or simple piece of code that can give me an idea in how to create it. I looking for something like in this [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a workaround to your requirement. Try it, may fit

```js
function reveal(){
  document.getElementById('h').className = 'open';
}
function closed(){
document.getElementById('h').className = 'close';

}
```

```css
div {height: 50px; background: green; color: white;}
#h {height: 0; transition: height 1s linear; background: blue}
#h.open {height: 50px}
#h.close {height: 0px}
```

```html
<div>This is the header area<br><button onclick="reveal()">Open the dropdown</button></div>
<div id="h" >I'm the hidden part of the page, Insert what ever you wanted</div>

<button onclick="closed()">Make this button as a division to hide the dropdown when click on below area </button>
```